# Would like to add a pseudo-pause button in my slide controls

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

I'd like to add a pause button ~for my embedded media~ between my slide controls on the bottom-right of the page.

Because my slides go to the next upon completion of my embedded media, to pause the slideshow I'm using this element:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"> || </button>
```

This works perfectly when I insert it in my HTML file, but I am unsure where/how to place it so it stays between the next/prev slide controls, not resizing with the slide. Would prefer to do this with CSS and not JS.

Thanks for any help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Show the rest of your code.

Comment: Sorry it's at drchloe.com/anxietytoolspreview/

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the HTML, you should be able to place your button code between the next & previous buttons.

[image: view html source]

And then to style it, you would want to either create a CSS class or use inline styles with the following attributes & values: `left: 30px; top: 26px; font-size: 25px;`

The full code:

```
<button class="enabled" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()" style="left: 30px; top: 26px; font-size: 25px;"> || </button>
```

It would make it look like this:

[image: pause button in action]

I did try using the javascript `document.getElementById('player').pause()`. It didn't seem to work. I couldn't find any elements that had the ID of `player`. But if you've already had that working in the past, then I'm sure you'll be covered in that regards.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far EnigmaRM!

But I don't think I am able to place it in the HTML since it's an aside? 

I think reveal.js somehow populates the aside element with the controls. When I place this element in the HTML file it resizes responsively and thus I can't position it to stay put within the controls.